# Cert-manager stopped renewing Let'S Encrypt certificates after upgrading to AKS 1.20.7

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, lets-encrypt, cert-manager

Our AKS cluster was configured to auto-renew Let's Encrypt certificates through Ingress Cert-Manager annotation and this worked perfectly until we upgraded to AKS 1.20.7. This then stopped working and the certificates started to expire without them being renewed - I double-checked all changes to K8S and CertManager APIs and reviewed all YAMLs, but I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong. Would appreciate any pointers.

My understanding is that as long as I add the "cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod-p9v2" to my ingress - the whole renewal should happen automatically - this is not happening though.

```
> kubectl cert-manager version
util.Version{GitVersion:"v1.4.0", GitCommit:"5e2a6883c1202739902ac94b5f4884152b810925", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.16.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

AKS version: 1.20.7

cat shipit-ingress-p9v2.yaml

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod-p9v2
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 15m
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: 15m
  generation: 4
  name: shipit-ingress-p9v2
  namespace: supplier
  resourceVersion: "147087245"
  uid: 6751dbff-83b1-48a1-a467-e75cc843ee79
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: planet9v2
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - xxx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    secretName: tls-secret-p9v2
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 10.240.0.5

>>kubectl get clusterissuer -o yaml letsencrypt-prod-p9v2
apiVersion: certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  annotations:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-05-29T13:31:10Z"
  generation: 2
  name: letsencrypt-prod-p9v2
  resourceVersion: "25493731"
  uid: 0e0e46f5-4cdf-42ea-a022-2dfe9ed56ad8
spec:
  acme:
    email: xxx
    http01: {}
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-prod
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
status:
  acme:
    uri: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/acct/76984529
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2020-05-29T13:31:11Z"
    message: The ACME account was registered with the ACME server
    reason: ACMEAccountRegistered
    status: "True"
    type: Ready


>>kubectl cert-manager inspect secret tls-secret-p9v2
...
Debugging:
        Trusted by this computer:       no: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2021-08-24T07:03:32Z is after 2021-08-22T06:40:20Z
        CRL Status:     No CRL endpoints set
        OCSP Status:    Cannot check OCSP: error reading OCSP response: ocsp: error from server: unauthorized



 kubectl  describe secret tls-secret-p9v2
Name:         tls-secret-p9v2
Namespace:    supplier
Labels:       certmanager.k8s.io/certificate-name=tls-secret-p9v2
Annotations:  certmanager.k8s.io/alt-names: shipit-dev-p9v2.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
              certmanager.k8s.io/common-name: shipit-dev-p9v2.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
              certmanager.k8s.io/ip-sans:
              certmanager.k8s.io/issuer-kind: ClusterIssuer
              certmanager.k8s.io/issuer-name: letsencrypt-prod-p9v2

Type:  kubernetes.io/tls

Data
====
tls.key:  1679 bytes
ca.crt:   0 bytes
tls.crt:  5672 bytes


kubectl get order
NAME                         STATE   AGE
tls-secret-p9v2-4123722043   valid   24d

[(⎈ |shipit-k8s-dev:supplier)]$ k describe order tls-secret-p9v2-4123722043
Name:         tls-secret-p9v2-4123722043
Namespace:    supplier
Labels:       acme.cert-manager.io/certificate-name=tls-secret-p9v2
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
Kind:         Order
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2021-07-31T04:12:42Z
  Generation:          4
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .:
          f:acme.cert-manager.io/certificate-name:
        f:ownerReferences:
          .:
          k:{"uid":"a1dec741-0fe7-42be-99d2-176c3d4cdf38"}:
            .:
            f:apiVersion:
            f:blockOwnerDeletion:
            f:controller:
            f:kind:
            f:name:
            f:uid:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:config:
        f:csr:
        f:dnsNames:
        f:issuerRef:
          .:
          f:kind:
          f:name:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:certificate:
        f:challenges:
        f:finalizeURL:
        f:state:
        f:url:
    Manager:    jetstack-cert-manager
    Operation:  Update
    Time:       2021-07-31T04:13:09Z
  Owner References:
    API Version:           certmanager.k8s.io/v1alpha1
    Block Owner Deletion:  true
    Controller:            true
    Kind:                  Certificate
    Name:                  tls-secret-p9v2
    UID:                   a1dec741-0fe7-42be-99d2-176c3d4cdf38
  Resource Version:        143545958
  UID:                     a646985b-6d44-4c99-bb39-ceb6c4919047
Spec:
  Config:
    Domains:
      shipit-dev-p9v2.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    http01:
      Ingress Class:  nginx
  Csr:                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
  Dns Names:
    shipit-dev-p9v2.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
  Issuer Ref:
    Kind:  ClusterIssuer
    Name:  letsencrypt-prod-p9v2
Status:
  Certificate:  LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJ.....
  Challenges:
    Authz URL:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/authz-v3/17660284180
    Config:
      http01:
        Ingress Class:  nginx
    Dns Name:           shipit-dev-p9v2.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    Issuer Ref:
      Kind:      ClusterIssuer
      Name:      letsencrypt-prod-p9v2
    Key:         AxP1pv5I087QVyKXIkGyT5pqlD4Aa-UYmJHAOgzHPu4.mIcOL5pBlkZJSpSUslpjJTC_hFunxNRCEA82VcfFAHE
    Token:       AxP1pv5I087QVyKXIkGyT5pqlD4Aa-UYmJHAOgzHPu4
    Type:        http-01
    URL:         https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/17660284180/Sh057Q
    Wildcard:    false
  Finalize URL:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/finalize/75003870/13444902230
  State:         valid
  URL:           https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/order/75003870/13444902230
Events:          <none>
```

Comment: Please check the resources certificate and order with a describe. Probably you will get more information where it stucks. Enrich your question please with some more information

Comment: Hi Manuel, added 'kubectl describe order/secret' as suggested.

Comment: Try to create another certificate resource, to see if it is working with let's encrypt. If so, you probably could try to delete one order resource. This should be recreated automatically then, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: I noticed the same on EKS 1.20, cert-manager (v1.4.0) is not auto renewing the certificates for some reason anymore and I constantly get emails from LE that this and this certificate will expire in 10 days.

Comment: @IgorC EKS v1.20.7-eks-d88609, cert-manager-v1.4.0, working smoothly. Have you checked controller logs?

Comment: @anemyte not sure how is that possible, this was already reported as a bug and fixed in later 1.4.x versions https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/4575 . Some kind of magic? :-)

Comment: @IgorC Honestly, I have no idea. I double-checked the version, it's `image: quay.io/jetstack/cert-manager-controller:v1.4.0` and it just works.

Comment: @anemyte how many certs are being managed and for how long you've been running v1.4.0? The only way I can think of that the bug would not affect you is if you have a cron job restarting cert-manager pods on regular bases OR the cert-manger pods are constantly crashing and relaunching since at the moment of restart it scans all the certificates and renews the ones that are about to expire (in the next 10 days by default). But if you say it is working then it is working, good for you :-)

Answer (score 7):

i was facing the same issue, updating the version of Cert-manager resolved the issue.

i was not on AKS but was using the GKE and i upgraded to the 1.5 cert-manager releases.

Currently as of now supported releases are the : **1.5 & 1.6**

[Releases](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/supported-releases/)

[Refer this Document](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/supported-releases/)

Based on my understanding Cert-manger stop supporting old release and support only the latest **2** releases.

i upgraded to **1.5** and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case had had to update the issuer yaml file. Before the update I had to change the apiVersion to cert-mamanager.io/v1.
After apply the issuer yaml file, my certificates were automaticly renewed.